# How to save values from multiple select box which is populated using ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have a list of select boxes. On change of each select box, i need to save the selected option in a variable (can be array not sure). As of now I am able to save the selected value in a variable if there is only ONE select box. How do i do it if I have a group of select boxes which has been populated using ng-repeat? I am able to display the changed value (in the h4 tag on the page). But I want to save that value into a variable. How do I do that?

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3bw4qka/3/)

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.GetValue = function(value){
 alert($scope.lengthPwd);
  }
  
 $scope.parameterList = [
 {id:"one", text:'Is it red in color?', done:true},
 {id:"two", text:'Is it square shaped?', done:false},
 {id:"three", text:'Does it have vowels?', done:false},
 {id: "four", text:'Allow Repeated characters?', done:true}
 ];

 $scope.range = function(min, max, step){
 step = step || 1;
 var input = [];
 for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
 return input;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
<label>Enter the total length
<select class="form-control col-md-6" ng-change="GetValue()" ng-model="lengthPwd">
<option ng-repeat="n in range(1,100)">{{n}}</option>
</select>
</label>

<ul class="row unstyled cards col-md-offset-1">
<li class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 card" ng-repeat="parameter in parameterList">
 <label id="sliderLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="parameter.done">
  <span>{{parameter.text}}</span>
 </label>
 <select class="form-control" ng-hide="!parameter.done" ng-disabled="anyNum=='any'" ng-change="GetAllVal()" ng-model="test" disabled>
  <option ng-repeat="n in range(1,100)">{{n}}</option>
 </select>
  <h4 id="{{parameter.id+test}}">{{parameter.id+test}}</h4>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your *problem* you want to get the values selected in the respective `<select>` right?

**Point 1:** I extremely recommend you to use [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ngRepeat`. `ngOptions` was made exactly for `<select>` tag.

**Point 2:** `ngRepeat` creates its own scope so no longer you can access **directly** the `ngModel` inside it, then you should use preferably `controller-as-syntax`.

You can do it using `ngModel` as `array`, like this:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("mainCtrl", function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.GetValue = function(value) {
      alert(vm.lengthPwd);
    }

    vm.parameterList = [  
       {  
          "id":"one",
          "text":"Is it red in color?",
          "done":true
       },
       {  
          "id":"two",
          "text":"Is it square shaped?",
          "done":false
       },
       {  
          "id":"three",
          "text":"Does it have vowels?",
          "done":false
       },
       {  
          "id":"four",
          "text":"Allow Repeated characters?",
          "done":true
       }
    ];

    vm.input = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      vm.input.push(i);
    }

    vm.set_value = function(index) {
      vm.parameterList[index].selectValue = vm.test[index];
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <pre ng-bind="main.test | json"></pre>
  <ul class="row unstyled cards col-md-offset-1">
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 card" ng-repeat="parameter in main.parameterList track by $index">
      <label id="sliderLabel">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="parameter.done">
        <span ng-bind="parameter.text"></span>
      </label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-if="parameter.done" ng-options="n for n in main.input" ng-model="main.test[$index]" ng-change="main.set_value($index)" ng-disabled="anyNum == 'any'">
        <option value="">Select</option>
      </select>
      <h4 id="{{parameter.id+test}}" ng-bind="parameter.id + main.test[$index]"></h4>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to store the values of the four select properties. I have copied your code and added the required logic.

The values chosen from the selectors will be stored in an array. You can access the values based on their position in the array. This is a limited solution but it should give you a hand in the right direction.

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngvalue-to-bind-the-model-to-an-array-of-objects)

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.GetValue = function(value){
 alert($scope.lengthPwd);
  }
  
 $scope.parameterList = [
 {id:"one", text:'Is it red in color?', done:true},
 {id:"two", text:'Is it square shaped?', done:false},
 {id:"three", text:'Does it have vowels?', done:false},
 {id: "four", text:'Allow Repeated characters?', done:true}
 ];
  
    $scope.valuesArr = [];

 $scope.range = function(min, max, step){
 step = step || 1;
 var input = [];
 for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
 return input;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
<label>Enter the total length
<select class="form-control col-md-6" ng-change="GetValue()" ng-model="lengthPwd">
<option ng-repeat="n in range(1,100)">{{n}}</option>
</select>
</label>

<ul class="row unstyled cards col-md-offset-1">
<li class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 card" ng-repeat="parameter in parameterList track by $index">
 <label id="sliderLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="parameter.done">
  <span>{{parameter.text}}</span>
 </label>
 <select class="form-control" ng-hide="!parameter.done" ng-disabled="anyNum=='any'" ng-change="GetAllVal()" ng-model="valuesArr[$index]" disabled>
      
            <option ng-repeat="n in range(1,100)" ng-value="n">{{n}}</option>


 </select>
  <h4 id="{{parameter.id+test}}">{{parameter.id+test}}</h4>
  
</li>
</ul>
  <h4> Stored Values -> {{valuesArr}}</h4>
</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $scope.boxValue = [];
$scope.boxValueChange = function (key,val) {
$scope.boxValue[key] = val;
console.log($scope.boxValue);
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/r3bw4qka/5/

Comment: Thank you. Almost there.. But the array is empty. Is there any other way please?

Comment: Did you change select drop down list like this:





<select  ng-change="boxValueChange(parameter.id, test)" class="form-control" ng-hide="!parameter.done" ng-disabled="anyNum=='any'" ng-change="GetAllVal()" ng-model="test" disabled>
  <option ng-repeat="n in range(1,100)">{{n}}</option>
 </select>